# Clone rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

I would like the dataframe to have the 1st column value (Beaver Valley) repeated for each hour for each day in the day column. So the dataframe should contain a column with the datetime stamp as well as the value corresponding to each day. Although in this dataframe the values are the same, they will be different for others.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Move `Date` to the index with `set_index`
- `asfreq` or `resample` to create an hourly index
- `ffill` to repeat existing values forward
- `reindex_axis` just to get columns back in the same order

---

```
df.set_index('Day').asfreq('H').ffill().reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Beaver Valley': [1, 2],
        'Day': pd.date_range('2017-05-01', periods=2)
    })

df

   Beaver Valley        Day
0              1 2017-05-01
1              2 2017-05-02
```

Applying the proposed solution

```
df.set_index('Day').asfreq('H').ffill().reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)

    Beaver Valley                 Day
0             1.0 2017-05-01 00:00:00
1             1.0 2017-05-01 01:00:00
2             1.0 2017-05-01 02:00:00
3             1.0 2017-05-01 03:00:00
4             1.0 2017-05-01 04:00:00
5             1.0 2017-05-01 05:00:00
6             1.0 2017-05-01 06:00:00
7             1.0 2017-05-01 07:00:00
8             1.0 2017-05-01 08:00:00
9             1.0 2017-05-01 09:00:00
10            1.0 2017-05-01 10:00:00
11            1.0 2017-05-01 11:00:00
12            1.0 2017-05-01 12:00:00
13            1.0 2017-05-01 13:00:00
14            1.0 2017-05-01 14:00:00
15            1.0 2017-05-01 15:00:00
16            1.0 2017-05-01 16:00:00
17            1.0 2017-05-01 17:00:00
18            1.0 2017-05-01 18:00:00
19            1.0 2017-05-01 19:00:00
20            1.0 2017-05-01 20:00:00
21            1.0 2017-05-01 21:00:00
22            1.0 2017-05-01 22:00:00
23            1.0 2017-05-01 23:00:00
24            2.0 2017-05-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to do it with a column which has datetime instead of date and it doesn't seem to be working. ie, I have 2017-05-01 00:00:00 in my day column and it's giving NaN's for all the rows. 
Please advice me what to change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to resample the DataFrame rows to an hourly frequency and forward-fill the 'Beaver Valley' values to fill the hourly slots created by the resampling. Here is a runnable example that I think does what you need, with different Beaver Valley values to illustrate the result of forward-filling:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Beaver Valley': [923.4, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
                   'DAY': pd.date_range(start='2017-05-01', periods=7)})

# By default, df.reset_index() reinserts the index of df as a column into df, which is what we need here.
df2 = df.set_index('DAY')
# To make sure the last day gets resampled into 24 hour-long intervals,
# append a NaN row before resampling (there may be a more readable way of doing this):
df3 = df2.reindex(pd.date_range(start=df2.index[0], periods=df2.shape[0]+1))
df3.index.rename('DAY', inplace=True)
df4 = df3.resample('h').ffill().reset_index()

df4.head()
# Output:
#                   DAY  Beaver Valley
# 0 2017-05-01 00:00:00          923.4
# 1 2017-05-01 01:00:00          923.4
# 2 2017-05-01 02:00:00          923.4
# 3 2017-05-01 03:00:00          923.4
# 4 2017-05-01 04:00:00          923.4

df4.tail()
# Output:
#                     DAY  Beaver Valley
# 164 2017-05-07 20:00:00          600.0
# 165 2017-05-07 21:00:00          600.0
# 166 2017-05-07 22:00:00          600.0
# 167 2017-05-07 23:00:00          600.0
# 168 2017-05-08 00:00:00            NaN
```

If desired, you can now drop the final placeholder row from the final dataframe:

```
df4 = df4[:-1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to do it with a column which has datetime instead of date and it doesn't seem to be working. ie, I have 2017-05-01 00:00:00 in my day column and it's giving NaN's for all the rows. 
Please advice me what to change.